# Spritekit Changing Gravity

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, physics, skspritenode

I've been trying to be able to alter gravity by using

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: 
UIEvent?) {
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
}
```

but that doesn't seem to change the gravity at all. When I use the same code in the didMove function, it works.

EDIT 1:

Here's the code for for my SKSpriteNode:

```
spaceship = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")

    spaceship.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    spaceship.setScale(0.1)
    spaceship.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    spaceship.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: spaceship.size.width / 2);


    addChild(spaceship)
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific about how you can find out that the gravity doesn't change ? In there any other elements in your SKScene that you are expecting to move/fall? If yes, did you set their physics bodies' mass/affectedByGravity properties?

Comment: Everything falls fine, but using that line of code doesn't stop the gravity like I want it too.

Comment: Are you expecting the sprite to stop immediately after turning off gravity?

Comment: Like @0x141E pointed out, you would need to change the velocity/speed property of your spaceship if you want it to stop right away and then go in an other direction, otherwise forces will still be applied on it.

Comment: Remember, gravity is a force. It causes acceleration. If you turn off gravity, you're not turning off motion, you're just turning off acceleration. If a body is moving when you turn off gravity, it will continue moving until some other force acts on it. Also, the line `spaceship.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true` in your code is doing nothing.

Comment: That makes sense. I used  spaceship.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0) to stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in `didMove` because the objects will have no forces applied to them, thus they are still

When you change the gravity mid-game, the objects are still in motion from the previous gravity--changing the gravity only affect /future/ forces applied to the objects.

You need to both change the gravity, AND the velocity of the nodes you want affected in your touch function to get the desired effect.

Also, for brevity, you can directly access the `dy` value without having to assign a new `CGVector` to it--this helps performance some as well.

`spaceship.physicsBody!.velocity.dy = 0`